# transform: rotate(); throws warnings in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, css-transforms

I am creating a webpage, and when debugging I get the following warnings.

```
    Unexpected value NaN parsing y1 attribute. markup.js:356:19
    Unexpected value NaN parsing y2 attribute. markup.js:356:19
    Unexpected value NaN parsing x1 attribute. markup.js:356:19
    Unexpected value NaN parsing x2 attribute. markup.js:356:19
```

Strangely enough, my html file has no markup.js file. No idea what it is.
I narrowed it down to an element that was causing these issues:

```html
<div style="transform: rotate(-20deg);">x</div>
```

Not only that, every time I hover over the element in the inspector, more warnings appear.

I am using Firefox  70.0.1 (64-bit). This problem does not seem to occur in Google Chrome.

The expected behaviour is of course that there should not be any warnings.

The messages are very annoying and I do not want to turn off warnings. Can someone tell me what is going on here?

Comment: I don't think it's related to transform. It's for sure something else

Comment: Is there any listener subscribed on that `<div>` ? What does the file markup.js do?

Comment: Its not the issue of `transform` as this property support almost all latest version of browsers

Comment: look at markup.js file in those line and see what the problem

Comment: @Andrew, there is no markup.js file. You can literally create a html file with that element and have warnings appear. markup.js is also not part of any extension I am using.

Comment: @לבנימלכה I've edited the question to have a code snippet. You can use it to see what markup.js is.

Comment: That's just the dev tools, don't bother with these messages. They do inject some js and svg elements to actually render the highlights over your elements, but it's not even inside your document per se.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It sure is related to transform. use the added code snippet to see for yourself.

Comment: @Kaiido why should I not bother with these messages? I want to know why the warnings appear in the first place.

Comment: These messages are not something **your** code is responsible of. There is nothing you can do on your side (apart from filling an issue to mozilla's bugzilla), but that really doesn't matter, because the only problem here is that the highlighter failed to draw one line. None of your users will ever care.

Comment: @Kaiido could you elaborate and maybe put it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *markup.js* file is part of the browser's internal dev-tools. It is not something your code is responsible of, nor that you can fix, and even less should care about.

The DOM highlighter uses some svg elements to render lines and highlight zones over your page. Something in there is producing a NaN value, which turns out to be invalid for svg `<line>` and `<linearGradient>` attributes.

This warning is displayed everytime such invalid attribute is set, if you wish, you can make it fire yourself:

```js
const line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
line.setAttribute('x1', NaN);
```

```html
Open Firefox's dev tools to see the warning.
```

But once again, **your code** is not responsible of this warning. Your users will only see it if they do highlight the element. I.e it is not something you want to care one more minute.

If you have free time though, you are welcome to open an issue on [mozilla's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) (quite surprised I can't find one already...)